# Are all snails edible? I get in my garden snails up to 10 cm long, and very fat

Tags: food-safety

I live in Iran and get a lot of very large snails and slugs in my garden. Like to know if ALL kinds of snails & slugs, after detoxification, are edible?

Comment: What do you mean with *after detoxification*? If you remove any possible toxins, what (else) is your criterion of *edible*?

Comment: Keep them from eating your salad greens, and eat the salad instead ;)

Comment: More to the point, please describe what you mean by "detoxification" here - would that be the "hold for 10 days and only eat ones that are still alive" step referred to in Megha's comment on dd263's answer?

Answer (score 1):

My gut feel is that cultivated "Escargot" is a good thing and I would be risk-averse.  However, [This article](http://www.motherearthnews.com/real-food/escargot-zmaz93jjztak) begs to differ and supports your thinking.

Comment: I find the assumption "do not worry about snail bait" dangerous - there are many things surrounding gardeners might try to get rid of these bastards, some officially allowed some not (also very locality dependent)...

Comment: @rackandboneman - it seems a little less dangerous when the instructions also include keeping the snails ten days before eating, and discarding any that die in that time - it makes it more likely that "survive long enough to be eaten" is a meaningful measure.  I still wouldn't try it myself, though.